# Client android application for site

Tags: java, android, performance, jsoup

I want to write a client application for a site (e.g. to read smth from site, add some comments, likes etc). I haven't got access to site sources and there isn't any API for work with it. So at my Android application I decided to parse this site (it has static pages) using : [JSOUP Library](http://jsoup.org/)
And using this library I'm going to write unofficial, but API for my purposes to work with this site, and then use it in my Android application.

Can somebody tell me, is this good practice or there are better ways to do? Is this good idea at all to parse site in Android device.

Comment: There's a risk that if they ever change the site (redesign, upgrade, whatever) your app will break.

Comment: It is not a good practice at all and must be the last way to go. Even a tiny change can break your parsing rules.

Comment: Good practice is not to write apps such that.

Comment: yes, I totally agree that there is a risk that my parsing rules will be broken, but what's another way to do such app?
What about sending and receiving http responses?

@piotrpo i'm java dev, but it's my first attempts with Android, so if you'll give me some idea for app to practice, i'll appreciate:) my idea was with this kind of app for myself.

Comment: As others have said this isn't a good practice for obvious reasons, but jsoup would be the way to do this if you really want to. Also the new Google Play content policy would allow the site owner to kick your app from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment - in general building your own application on top of the third party www service is not a good idea. If you want to do it anyway you have 2 options:

Use jSoup (or any other html parser if exists) and parse third party content on the device

Set up some middleware server to parse content and serve it in some more convenient way.

The second option has a little advantages - you can fix application without forcing users to update it and probably you'll save a bit of device's bandwidth. Of course disadvantage is that you have to pay for server.

General problem with applications like that is that every single change with layout, skin, server configuration can cause your application to stop working, as well as parsing html needs much more work that just connect to existing API.
More over - publishing your application can cause some legal issues (copyright) and is against [Google Play's policy](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to: Drive
>   affiliate traffic to a website or Provide a webview of a website not
>   owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the
>   website owner/administrator to do so)